# What should be done with questions that ask for nonexistent resources?

Tags: discussion

Today, someone [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068942/swift-runtime-documentation#comment37116118_24068942) where they could find official documentation for the Swift runtime. The question was quickly downvoted and judged too broad (because it asked for too many things) and/or off-topic (because it asked for off-site resources).

I disagree with both, and here's why.

I don't believe that the question was particularly broad. It asked for just one very specific thing: the documentation of the Swift runtime. This documentation [exists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) for Apple's Objective-C runtime, and OP is very clearly asking for the Swift equivalent. To "follow the rule" as outlined by detractors, the asker should have split his question into half a dozen questions:

- How does method dispatch work in the Swift language?
- How can I dynamically find the layout of a Swift class?
- How can I dynamically add methods to a Swift class?
- etc.

These questions are only helpful to people who need to do interop with the language (or want to poke around), and these people are unlikely to need just one of the resources. In fact, the answer to all of these questions would probably be a single link to the official Swift documentation. This is different from, say, someone asking how to format a date in C# and someone referring them to the root of MSDN: you don't need to understand the whole Microsoft ecosystem to be able to format a date in C#. You don't even really need to understand how dates work. However, to do interop with a language, you need to understand the language's runtime.

For this reason, I do not believe that the question was "too broad".

A detractor argued that questions that ask for "favorite off-site resources" are off-topic. I do not like how it has been interpreted for this question. This rule was implemented years ago to stop questions like "what is the best site to learn C++?", which were open-ended questions that could attract hundreds of answers, with no definitive one. Asking for *the official documentation* isn't an open-ended question: there would be **just one good, definitive answer**.

Which brings us to what I think is the biggest issue: *this question can only be negatively answered*. The appropriate documentation hasn't been released. In my opinion, the fact that a question can't be answered doesn't automatically make it bad. There are several kinds of bad questions that can't be answered:

- Questions that are too broad ("How do I create a compiler from scratch?"). These are bad because there are too many approaches to solve the problem, with different tradeoffs. An answer that satisfies the asker's needs may not satisfy the needs of the next person visiting it.
- Questions that don't make sense ("How can I prevent an exception from being thrown in Java when I use a method on a null pointer?"). These are posted by people without an understanding of the technologies they are using, and there is no other good answer than "you need to learn how it works".

However, especially when dealing with closed-source technologies, there are good questions that genuinely can't be answered, simply because the answer is not available to the general public. This doesn't make them bad questions, and if anything it's more a problem with the technology than with the question itself. People ask questions all the time about open source software that you couldn't answer if it was closed source.

In my opinion, this question was closed because of answerer cynicism: "I can't answer this, and therefore this question is bad". Which I find unfortunate, because OP did a decent amount of research before asking: he claims he read the official Swift book, watched the WWDC videos, searched for source code, and only then, turned to Stack Overflow. He apparently did his homework before asking, and it only so happened that the question doesn't have a public answer.

This is not the same as [asking for customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). The decision of releasing source code or documentation may entirely rest in the hands of Apple, but without knowing that this documentation simply hadn't been released, OP shouldn't be blamed for not immediately turning to Apple. OP had good reasons to believe that this could be available somewhere: as mentioned very early in this post, the same documentation exists for the Objective-C language.

So, what should be done with questions that ask for resources that don't exist? Is it acceptable to let them live, or should they be closed as off-topic/too broad?

Comment: I don't see how there's any room for disagreement that the question was asking for an off-site resource. Those are explicitly off-topic, because even in the case of an "official" resource, links can always break over time. SO is not trying to replace Google.

Comment: My personal opinion is that it should be closed. If the documentation exists, a simple Google search will bring it up (given the hype around Swift). Where do you draw the line? Should we also allow "Where can I find the jQuery documentation"? Only if the OP also states he read a book about jQuery? Because allowing this question would set a precedent IMO. I don't think these questions add value to the site.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, what I'm saying is that the use of this close reason has changed since it was created.

Comment: @kapa, this is like the difference between false and null. No answer isn't the same as a negative answer. Do you think that the question will never pop up again between now and the time Apple releases the documentation, if it ever happens? I'd say that if this question helps people find that the documentation isn't available, then it does add value. If a user asks where to find jQuery documentation even though he said he looked for it, he can legitimately be downvoted into oblivion because he clearly didn't look for it very long (and this also happens all the time).

Comment: @zneak If the question pops up again, we close it again. We are already used to the same questions being asked all the time, unfortunately.

Comment: @kapa, of course it will be closed again, but you're sidestepping the important issue. Closed questions are questions that add no value to the site, as you said. If the fact that this has now been asked helps avoid duplicates, then this question at least had some value.

Comment: @zneak Off-topic questions should not be kept open just to avoid some duplicates.

Comment: All of these petty rules are what's destroying this community. Eventually, we won't be able to post a question until we have already posted that question (see how difficult it can be).

Answer (score 15):

We're not a resource-locating service, whether the resource being sought exists or not.

The correct close reason is *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."*

Comment: That's a terrible reason to close it.It isn't asking for a FAVORITE anything. It is asking for a very specific (the OFFICIAL) thing.

Comment: @JasonN: Looks like you're cherry-picking one word from the close reason and focusing on that to the exclusion of everything else.  "Favorite" is the least of our worries here.

Comment: I've now seen multiple people interpret this the same way as me. Somebody should really rewrite that description to say what is meant. As standing it causes confusion and frustration.

Comment: I'd be happy to coordinate with the other mods and remove the word "favorite" from the close reason, if it's that much of a problem.  It really is not all that important.  It's there because people tend to ask "what is the best," which is not a problem statement.  Nor is it our business to determine what is "official."

Comment: I think the rule is fine. I think your interpretation is overly broad and the enforcement drives good questions from the site. I see this pops up over and over every few months using this closure reason on a question that there is no way it could apply do. You really think you are going to get 50 people tell the OP what the best SWIFT documentation is? The rule was made to shut down Emacs/VI wars, not this.

Comment: No, the rule was made to stop people from using Stack Overflow as a search engine or recommendation engine.  Emacs/VI wars can be closed as "Too Broad" or "Primarily Opinion-Based."

Comment: Google doesn't answer everything, and there is definitely space for questions like this on SO. the question is, "IS the site better or worse with these questions." Def better.

Answer (score -1):

> someone asked where they could find official documentation for the Swift runtime

Questions seeking official resources are allowed. We don't allow recommendation requests because they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam, but requests for official resources *cannot* have that problem by nature. See [@Stephen Ostermiller's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541) to [Overhauling our community's closure reasons and guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417008/11107541), and [@Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386006/11107541) to [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479/11107541).

We're here to do fact-based Q&A. If the question is about where to find such official resources, and the fact is that no such resources currently exist, then I think an answer that says "*At the time of this writing, no such official resource exists. <any relevant facts to back up the claim>*" is suitable. There could be problems with the answer becoming outdated in the future (a good kind of problem, I think), but if that happens, whoever finds out can write a new answer, and eventually, the best answer will rise to the top (or people can sort by trending). If the original answerer finds out, they can edit their answer post.